# how do I run ruby unit tests within sublime (sublime text 3)?

Tags: ruby, tdd, sublimetext3

How do I run ruby unit tests within sublime (sublime text 3)? currently using rspec and terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for package [`TestRSpec`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TestRSpec). Which looks like this:[image: TestRSpec screenshot]

Comment: did install the TestRspec package but had encountered this:

`ERROR: Could not find 'spec/' folder traversing back from the file (path mentioned)
INFO: Error occurred, see more in 'View -> Show Console
INFO: Project root None`

Comment: Well that is issue in your project which you did not provide.  `Rspec` plugin expects you to have `spec/` folder in your project.  You should create it and store there your tests.